# Where is the correct place to define password validation in ASP.NET 5.0 MVC Identity now identityconfig.cs has been removed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

In previous projects I have defined password validation for .NET identity in the `identityconfig.cs` file in App_start folder. The following would be under the ApplicationUserManager class:

```
// Configure validation logic for passwords 
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator 
            { 
                RequiredLength = 6, 
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true, 
                RequireDigit = true, 
                RequireLowercase = true, 
                RequireUppercase = true, 
            };
```

In latest versions of .NET MVC I'm using `identityconfig.cs` and App_Start have been removed.

I've been unable to find a clear answer on where these variables can now be set. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this by doing the following in `startup.cs`

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add Entity Framework services to the services container.
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

        // Add Identity services to the services container.
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(o => {
            // configure identity options
            o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false; ;
            o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        })

            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about Identity 3 in ASP.NET Core MVC 6
You need to implement your custom logic in your object by implementing the interface `IPasswordValidator<T>`.

Then in your Startup.cs under the `IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method
add the following

```
services.AddScoped<IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>, YOUR_OBJECT>();
```

where ApplicationUser is the user object used by your Identity implementation

Identity 3 has been split into interfaces for extensibility

Answer (score 1):

That's part of configuring your `ApplicationUserManager` class. It's just a class, so it doesn't matter *where* it goes.

However, since I keep all my entities in a separate class library (including my `ApplicationUser` entity), I like to create an `Identity` directory there where I put `ApplicationUser`, `ApplicationUserManager`, `ApplicationSignInManager`, etc., each in their own .cs file named after the class, which is pretty much the best practice for any class. Microsoft likes to throw everything in a couple of .cs files, but that's technically bad practice.

That's just the way I do it, though. You're free to organize your solution however you feel makes the most sense to your application.